# Which exact Windows 7 ISO is required for Boot Camp v6.1.0 on macOS High Sierra? Mid 2010 MBP

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, bootcamp, windows

Try as I may, I cannot get Boot Camp on macOS High Sierra to accept any Windows 7 installer DVD (or ISO) I have tried yet. Although Boot Camp seems to be able to accept a flash drive, when I try one I get the error:

*The installer disc could not be found. Insert your Windows installer disc and wait a few seconds for the disc to be recognized.*

So, since this is a **Mid 2010 MacBook Pro** (which has an optical drive) I've tried a legit Win7 SP1 retail DVD (checksum verified), but then I get this error:

*Boot Camp only support installing Windows 7 on this Mac. Please insert a USB drive or DVD which contains a full version of Windows 7.*

Does that mean "full" as in all editions of Win7, so Home, Pro, Ultimate, etc?? Documentation for this online is very sparse and lacking, I've found.

Comment: I think you might need Boot Camp 5.1 for that Mac - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_Camp_(software) [Not completely certain but may be worth a shot].

Comment: Ah - I found a list... v5 or v4 depending on precise Mac model [scroll way down...] https://support.apple.com/HT205016

Comment: All these downloads from Apple are .EXE files...? I need the actual .APP file program for the older v4 version of Boot Camp to run it inside of macOS High Sierra. Any idea where I can find that?

Comment: I'm going to have to either give up or maybe try installing Windows manually without Boot Camp Assistant. Far as I can tell, the old versions of BC Assistant .APP just _do not_ exist anywhere on the internet whatsoever.

Comment: Windows 7 comes in either "upgrade" or "full" versions. A clean install of Windows 7 can be made on a PC by using either a "full" version or an "upgrade version DVD. However, during the process of installing, an "upgrade" Windows 7 version DVD will ask for you to insert an acceptable previous Windows version (i.e. 2000, XP or Vista) in the DVD drive. On Macs, there is no way to eject the "upgrade" Windows 7 version DVD and insert the previous Windows version DVD, therefore an "upgrade" Windows 7 version DVD can not be used. You must use a "full" Windows 7 version DVD.

Comment: Did you alter the Boot Camp Assistant in any way? If so, edit your question and explain what changes you made. I ask this question, because I have a 2011 iMac with the latest version of High Sierra and I am not experiencing the same behavior from the Boot Camp Assistant as you are. Since both ours Macs have DVD drives and are a year apart, the behavior should be similar with respect to installing Windows 7.

Comment: Thanks, Dave. I have not altered the Boot Camp Assistant program whatsoever. It's a new install of macOS High Sierra.

Comment: ...assuming that's what is meant by "full" installer for Windows 7 then yes, I have the full, standalone installer for Windows 7 Pro SP1.

Comment: Have you tried downloading [Windows 7 SP1 from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7)? You will need your product key to enable the download.

Comment: It is not that I could not figure out the answer to your question. It is that I would have to remove Windows 10 and Ubuntu from my 2011 iMac to test my answer. I am not willing to do that. However, if you need the procedure to install Windows 7 or 10 by using a flash drive on your Mac, let me know. This procedure would not use the Boot Camp Assistant (except for maybe downloading the Windows Support Software).

Comment: Thanks for the help, @DavidAnderson. I'm just trying to sell this laptop, so it's not super crucial that I get Windows installed (since it already has macOS High Sierra). I can try installing Windows without Boot Camp Assistant since that seems to be my only option.

Answer (score 2):

## Steps to Install Windows 7 without Using the Boot Camp Assistant

Although a Windows 7 can be installed without using the both the Boot Camp Assistant and a Windows 7 installation DVD, the using a the DVD greatly simplifies the procedure. Since you have a working optical drive, I the steps given below will include using this drive.

> Note: According to Apple, you need a Windows 7 DVD with Service Pack 1 (SP1) included.

### Create the Flash Drive with the Windows Support Software

1. Use the Disk Utility to erase a 8 GB or larger flash drive. For name, use `WSS`. For format, use `MS-DOS (FAT)`. For scheme, use `Master Boot Record`.
2. Download the "Windows Support Software" for you Mac from the website [Install Windows 7 on your Mac using Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205016#version5).
3. Copy the "Windows Support Software" to the flash drive.
4. Under Safari preferences, select `Advance`. Make sure `Show Develop menu in menu bar` is checked off. See image below.

   [image]
5. From a window opened in Safari, go to the website https://sourceforge.net/projects/gptfdisk/. While at this website, select `Develop->User Agent->Microsoft Edge` from the menu bar, then click the `Download` button on the webpage.
6. From the downloaded files, copy `gdisk64.exe` to the root folder on the flash drive.
7. Either close the Safari window or select `Develop->User Agent->Default` from the menu bar.

### Install Windows 7

> Note: If during the installation of Windows, the Mac restarts back to macOS, then open the "Startup Disk" pane of the "System Preferences" application and restart back to Windows. The installation of Windows will continue from where it left off.

1. Use the Disk Utility application to partition the internal drive.  Add a new partition named `BOOTCAMP` with the format `MS-DOS (FAT)`.

   > Note: after partitioning completes, you may have to quit and then open the Disk Utility application to see the correct results.
2. Insert the Windows 7 DVD in the optical drive.
3. Insert the Windows Support Software flash drive in a USB port.
4. Restart the Mac and immediately hold down the option key. Release the key when the Startup Manager icons appears. Select the icon labeled `Windows`.
5. When the window below appears, select `Custom (advanced)`.

   [image]
6. The `BOOTCAMP` partition should be either 3 or 4. Remember the number, you will need this later.
7. Press the <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> key combination to open a Command Prompt window.
8. Enter the command shown below. Remember the drive letter (name) for the  `WSS` volume.

   ```
   wmic logicaldisk get name,volumename
   ```
9. Enter the command below to execute `gdisk`. If drive letter (name) for the `WSS` volume is not `D:`, then make the appropriate substitution.

   ```
   D:\gdisk64 \\.\PhysicalDrive0
   ```
10. Change the type of partitioning to hybrid. If the `BOOTCAMP` partition is number 3, then enter the commands given below.

    ```
    r
    h
    2 3
    y
    ff
    n
    07
    y
    n
    w
    y
    ```

    Otherwise, if the `BOOTCAMP` partition is number 4, then enter the commands given below.

    > Note: If macOS is using encryption, the substitute `ac` for `af` below.

    ```
    r
    h
    2 3 4
    y
    af
    n
    ab
    n
    07
    y
    w
    y
    ```
11. Enter the `exit` command to close the Command Prompt window.
12. Click on the `Refresh` button.
13. Select the `BOOTCAMP` partition. Before clicking the `Next` button, you will have to format the partition by first clicking on `Drive options (advanced)`, then clicking on the `Format` button.
14. After finishing installing Windows 7, execute the `setup` application on the Windows Support Software flash drive.